# Not able to receive any push message on my Blackberry app

Tags: urbanairship.com

I am not able to receive any push message on my Blackberry app using Urban Airship.while sending message i am getting this message from urban airship"Received push with invalid authorization on platform BLACKBERRY". And urban airship shows my BB device pin is registered.

(Used UrbanAirshipPushClient5X lib in my code)
Device is already have BIS(Blackberry Internet Services)

Before 1 yr same code is working fine but now something wrong please suggest me any update or changes on client or server side.
(developing an app in BB OS 5 +.)